# Checking if an answer is empty or not

Tags: ruby

I want to create a loop for the user until he gives me an number. But I don't know the right method to check if it's an number or an string.
Well something like this.

```
puts "Enter your age."
age = gets.chomp.to_i
while age.empty?
    age = gets.chomp.to_i
end
```

Empty methods results this into an error.

Comment: "An error?" What error? There are several ways this could be handled, but you can't check if a number is "empty" because it makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below code:

```
puts "Enter your age."
age = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue nil
while age.nil?
 age = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue nil
end
```

Comment: What if one were to enter `"-34\n"`? In the interest of DRYness, consider changing the second line to `age = nil`. You may wish to move the `puts` line into the loop (even though the OP has not done so).

Comment: You can even do this as one liner: `age = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue nil while age.nil?`

Comment: This is working absolutely fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

[Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) with the keyword `break` is commonly used for such tasks.

```
r = /
    \A    # match beginning of string
    [1-9] # match a digit greater than zero
    \d*   # match zero or more digits
    $     # match end of line
    /x    # free-spacing regex definition mode

loop do
  print "Enter your age: "
  age = gets[r]
  break age.to_i unless age.nil?
end
```

If `"34\n"` were entered, the line in the terminal would appear as follows:

```
Enter your age: 34
```

See [Kernel#print](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print). If [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) were used, the following would be displayed.

```
Enter your age:
34
```

Note that the first anchor (`\A`) matches the beginning of the *string* whereas the second anchor (`$`) matches the end of a *line*. (Mixing beginning and end of string and line anchors is unusual.) One could instead write `age = gets.chomp[/\A\d+\z/]`, where `\z` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to **filter also negative integers**, you can check if the input contains only numbers. For example:

```
age = nil
loop do
  puts "Enter your age: "
  age = gets.chomp
  break if (age.scan(/\D/).empty? & !age.empty?)
end
puts "Your age is #{age}"
```

`age = nil` required to initialise the variable and use outside the loop. Or need to use `@age`.

`.scan(/\D/)` generates an array containing each single characters of the string which is not a digit `\D`. So, if the array is empty, it means that the string is made of just digits. For example:

```
p "my age is 30".scan(/\D/) #=> ["m", "y", " ", "a", "g", "e", " ", "i", "s", " "]
p "30".scan(/\D/) #=> []
```