# I want to check if a variable is assigned to an integer

Tags: ruby

I have a variable assigned to user input. I want to check if the user input is an integer. how do I do that?

```
a = gets
```

Comment: More or less the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668704/checking-if-an-answer-is-empty-or-not)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5661466/5345794

Comment: `gets` returns a `String`, so `a` will *never* reference an `Integer`, it will *always* be a `String`.

Comment: What Jörg said. Also maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235863/125816

Comment: You can use this trick: ```a = Integer(gets) rescue 'should be integer'```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to check: `gets` returns a `String`, so `a` will *never* reference an `Integer`, it will *always* be a `String`. There is no possible way that `a` will ever reference an `Integer` in the code you posted.

Comment: I think, *never* is a bit too strong. The method may have been redefined, or the context is executed inside a class where `gets` doesn't necessarily return a `String`....

Comment: @user1934428: "in the code you posted". In that code, "never" is the correct estimation.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Right you are. From the way the OP wrote it, we must assume that this statement is not just a line picked from a large application, and in this case, *never* is indeed correct. I didn't consider that this might just be the first line of a complete application. Thanks for having me corrected.